# MySQLdump hangs with routines

Tags: function, mysql, procedures, routines

I am trying to use a bat file to do a complete copy of a database to a different database. There are procedures and functions which need to be transferred over which is my biggest problem.

When I use

```
mysqldump -u user -p password db1 -v -R | mysql -u user -p password db2
```

It will copy all of the tables no problem, but hangs when it comes to the procedures and functions with this

```
..
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
```

I have quite a few functions and procedures that needs to be copied over. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ROOT CAUSE

- When you mysqldump stored procedures, it requires locking `mysql.proc`
- You are loading the same table you are dumping from AND IT'S LOCKED !!!

## SUGGESTION

Load the data first. Write Stored Procedures to a text file. The, load the code.

```
mysqldump -u user -p password db1 -v --skip-routines | mysql -u user -p password db2
mysqldump -u user -p password db1 -t -d --routines > stored_procs_from_db1.sql
mysql -u user -p password db2 < stored_procs_from_db1.sql
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!